# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S2 have duplicate calendar events?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync, samsung-kies, google-calendar, outlook

Why does my Samsung Galaxy S2 have duplicate calendar events?  I am using Outlook calendar and have downloaded the Google calendar to allow it to sync.  When I use the Samsung Kies Program to sync the Samsung Galaxy S2 I end up with multiply duplicates of some of the events and not others.

Comment: By duplicate events, do you mean duplicate notifications of the same event? If so, this is just a matter of turning off notifications on one of the calendar apps.